# How to disable the pinch to zoom in android studio emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-emulator, gesture

When I try to use the Android studio emulator, the pinch to zoom appears by clicking on some shortcuts accidentally and I need to know how to cancel the pinch to zoom option.

Answer (score 17):

I haven't found a correct way to disable it but this is what works for me when I accidentally enable the pinch functionality:

On the emulator toolbar **click the magnifying glass button two times**, one to zoom in and one to reset to the normal zoom level. Done! After that the pinch functionality should be gone

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the pinch gesture this way:

With the emulator open, click on the **3 dots** to open the emulator settings.

Then click on the `Settings` category and change:
`Send keyboard shortcuts` to `Virtual device`